# Clearing responses from Google Sheet at night

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Let me begin with ... I am a school secretary and have next to no knowledge with scripts. I have created a Google form for parents to fill out each day which dumps into Sheets. I have managed to figure out the script below (along with a trigger to delete the content each night) so that the spreadsheet is clear each morning.  However, the rows aren't being deleted. The new responses are just added 100 rows down below the newly emptied rows each day. I have tried 1,000 different combinations of DelRsp, deleteResponses, etc. but just keep getting errors. I'm about to pull my hair out! I would like to retain the first row each time with the column headers.  Just want to get rid of the responses. I would appreciate ANY help!  Thanks! This is what I currently have:

```
function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Form Responses 1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  sheet.getRange('A2:H300').clearContent();}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

There is the option to **delete** the rows instead:

```
function clearRange() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    const form_size = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
    sheet.deleteRows(2, form_size);
 }
```

**Note that** before you start employing this solution:

- just for the first time, manually delete all the rows, starting from
  the second row until the row before the new entry will be added.
- As a result, in the morning, the new entries will start from the
  second row.

### References:

- [deleteRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: Thank you for your response!  You are a genius.  I think it's going to work!

Comment: Ok, it seemed to work, but the new responses are actually still showing up the next day but starting on the 130th row (or whatever row is next after the first day's responses).  Does that make sense?

Comment: @KARINHAWKINS did you manually delete the first bunch of empty rows before you execute the function as it suggested also in my answer?

Comment: @KARINHAWKINS also the function has to be timely triggered every morning before the new entries are arrived. Did you set up a time trigger to execute that function every early morning?

Comment: I deleted the rows, yes. I've tried a few days in a row.  The trigger is set for midnight each night.

Comment: @KARINHAWKINS I can't reproduce the error. Please go the views execution page to see what are the errors if any . Also maybe make sure that the form sheet is not protected .